# Get Azure Website/WebApp hostnames as a variable using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I'm trying to get the hostnames of an Azure webapp/website and add it to a variable. So far I have

```
    Get-AzureWebsite -Name $WebAppName1
```

This returns all information about the webapp/website. Not sure how to grab only the host name.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to save the output to a variable and examine it:

```
$website = Get-AzureWebsite -Name $WebAppName1 
$website | Get-Member
```

and look for the property you are interested in. Note that the property you are interested in may be a subproperty for another property. For a WebApp you would do this (I don't have a WebSite to demonstrate):

```
$webapp = Get-AzureRmWebApp -blablabla
$webapp.DefaultHostName
$webapp.EnabledHostNames
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks.